# Product prices inconsistent with tax

Tags: checkout, price, magento-1, tax

I have product prices in admin inserted including tax.

When adding product to cart, for vat exclusive countries, the cart and checkout correctly show the price minus tax.

But, on the product view and listing page, the product is shown including tax.

Is this a simple config issue i do not see?

Answer (score 0):

You can check price display setting from admin

> Admin >> Sales >> Tax >> Price Disaply Setting.

[image]

You can change price display setting for list,detail or shopping cart pages.

Comment: this is not the issue.  All settings are correct.  The  prices display correctly in cart and checkout but not in product list or view